# Firebase google authentication issue in Firefox OS app

Tags: firefox, firebase, firefox-os, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use the firebase google authentication in my packaged Firefox OS app but keep running into the same issue. Here is my login code.

```
$scope.googleLogin = () => {
  mainRef.authWithOAuthRedirect("google", (error, authData) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      new Notification("There was an error logging in, please try again");
    }
    else {
      $scope.users.$add({
        username: authData.google.displayName,
        uid: authData.auth.uid,
      })

      localStorage.setItem("user", authData.google.displayName);
      localStorage.setItem("localUID", authData.auth.uid);
      localStorage.setItem("avatar", authData.google.profileImageURL);

      $state.go("app.playlists");

      new Notification("Thanks for logging in!");
    }
  })
}
```

When this code runs in the Firefox OS 2.0 simulator i get this error in the console:
The connection to wss://s-dal5-nss-28.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=firefoxnote was interrupted while the page was loading.

Comment: Does this happen consistently? Or was it intermittent?

Comment: Looks like the usual error when reloading a page, the last websocket will get closed, if the websocket doesn't reconnect then you should have something that will reconnect it.

Comment: @DavidEast it happens consistently, I also did some more testing and it also happens in an ionic app installed on my nexus 6.